# $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^q $ what does $f'(c)$ mean geometrically?

Tags: calculus

When $q=1$, it is the slope of the tangent line. 
But in general, is it correct to say that is the tangent direction on the point $f(c)$?

Comment: Are you asking about $t \mapsto (f_1(t), \ldots, f_q(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^q$? If so, the derivative here can be thought of as a velocity vector at point $f(t)$, where the derivative is computed coordinate-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $q>1$, it isn't very common to think of the domain $\Bbb R$ and the codomain $\Bbb R^q$ in the same $\Bbb R^{1+q}$ coordinate system. Instead, it's more common to consider $f$ as a parametrisation of a curve in $\Bbb R^q$, or similarly the path of some particle moving around in $\Bbb R^q$, where the input to the function is interpreted as time.

Take, as an example, $q=2$ and $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. If you draw this in $\Bbb R^3$ as a graph, it will give a helix around the $x$-axis. But it is more common to see it visualised as a parameterized circle in $\Bbb R^2$.

In the graph visualisation, the vector $(1,f'(c))$ is indeed the direction that is tangent to the graph at $(c,f(c))$, as you suggested.

In the parametrisation visualisation, $f'(c)$ is the *velocity vector* at time $c$. Its direction is tangent to the curve at $f(c)$, and its length is equal to the speed of the particle.

Comment: The speed of the particle is proportional to the slope no?

Comment: For $q=1$, the slope is _equal to_ the _velocity_ of the particle. For higher $q$, we don't really use the word "slope".

Comment: The speed is the length of the velocity vector.